# Open pop is not connecting with gmail

Tags: pop3, openpop, gmail-pop

I am using open pop to connect one of my `gmail` account.
And I made setting and enable pop setting in `gmail` Account.
but still it's not connecting and not fetching emails. same thing is working for `hotmail` and other email service provider. But my own `gmail` is not connecting.

Thease are the gmail setting i am using.

```
host pop.gmail.com
port 995
```

and this the error message i am getting.

```
OpenPOP.POP3.InvalidPasswordException was thrown
```